# Apex HTTP Post method parameters

Tags: apex, apexrest

Can a REST Http post method get a custom object( containing other custom objects and standard objects ) as a parameter if so how would the http post request body look like ? Thank you all for reading this : )

```apex
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myCustomREST/v1/*')
global with sharing class RestCustomClass {
global class myCustomRequest {
    public MyCustomObj customObj;
    public Account account;
    public Contact contact;

}
```

.....

Answer (score 6):

The [RestRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm#apex_System_RestRequest_requestBody) documentation explains that:

> If the Apex method has no parameters, then Apex REST copies the HTTP
>   request body into the RestRequest.requestBody property.

So that allows you to take control of the deserialization into an instance of the class you have defined by using [JSON.deserialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserialize):

```
@HttpPost  
global static void post() {
    myCustomRequest data = (myCustomRequest) JSON.deserialize(
            RestContext.request.requestBody.toString(),
            myCustomRequest.class
            );
    // Use the data
}
```

The serialization/deserialization supports custom and standard objects.

Comment: Thanks for your input dear Keith, I really really appreciate it.

Comment: That means we can have method annotated with `@HttpGet` and no parameters in the signature and use `requestBody` as mentioned above? The reason I ask this question is I always thought `@HttpGet` method should have parameters and `@HttpPost` method no paramters.

Comment: @javanoob A GET is different in that the parameters are encoded in the URL (so not as JSON) and most conveniently obtained from RestRequest.params. I've never used method parameters for a GET...